# Dial code from country code (mcc) using Cordova, ionic

Tags: cordova, country-codes, mobile-country-code

How do I get dial code from `mcc` (mobile country code)?

> eg. India has `404` or `405` as `mcc` for various network operators, `+91` as the standard dial-code.

I am using `cordova-plugin-sim` [plugin](https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-sim) of `cordova`.

When I use `window.plugins.sim.getSimInfo` function, I get this info through a `JSON` response (I have not shown all the info for privacy/security reasons):

```
callState: 0
carrierName: "BSNL MOBILE"
countryCode: "in"
dataActivity: <some number>
deviceId: "<some id as integer>"
deviceSoftwareVersion: "<a 2 digit code>"
isNetworkRoaming: false
mcc: "404"
mnc: "66"
networkType: 10
phoneNumber: "<my mobile number without dial code>"
phoneType: 1
simSerialNumber: "<sim serial number, long one>"
simState: 5
subscriberId: "<subscriber Id, long one>"
```

Do I need to use another API to get dial code using the information that I get from `window.plugins.sim.getSimInfo`?

Comment: Have you tried this https://github.com/dtmtec/cordova-plugin-carrier ?

Comment: It will only give me a subset of information that I get using `cordova-plugin-sim`. So not enough @SANATSHUKLA